# How to simplify ng-switch with similar elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch, ng-bind

I have the following code:

```
<span ng-switch="status">
    <span ng-switch-when="NOT OK">
        <span style="color: red;" ng-bind="status"></span>
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-when="OK">
        <span style="color: green;" ng-bind="status"></span>
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>
        <span ng-bind="status"></span>
    </span>
 </span>
```

There is any way to optimize this code? I think i have some repetition of ng-binding ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use `ng-class` and set your colors in css rules

```
<span ng-bind="status" 
      ng-class="{'green-class': status=='OK', 'red-class': status=='NOT OK'}" ></span>
```

Or do similar using `ng-style`

Comment: Can you post the `ng-style` alternative? I tried a similar syntax but isn't working.